# Why m-xylene is more basic than o- and p-xylene in tetrafluoroboric acid?

Tags: organic-chemistry, aromatic-compounds

[image]

According to me, the more stable sigma complex should be ortho and para xylene as it stabilizes the positive charge through hyperconjugation but in the book the order is meta xylene is more stable than ortho para xylene. Why is hyperconjugation destabilizing in this case?

Source:
KS Verma Organic Chemistry for JEE Advanced

Comment: Draw resonance structures - these aren't benzyl cations.

Comment: For help, goo to Search on Chemistry at the top of the page and type m-xylene.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What stabilizes the carbocation is when the methyl groups are ortho/para *to the protonation site.* (The protonation site is where the proton actually adds to the hydrocarbon molecule.) Getting both methyl groups into these favored positions requires them to be meta *to each other*. So the most stable cation isomers are derived from meta-xylene.

Comment: But how do you know that the protonation site in meta xylene is not on the one of the -ch3 groups? That would make the meta isomer less stable than ortho/para.

Comment: It's not so much that we know, rather the molecule knows. Given a choice, meta-xylene will preferentially accept a proton where the methyl groups are favorably placed. In fact, trying to protonate elsewhere invites a hydride-shift rearrangement to get the carbocation into the more favored configuration.